# ngrx-store-freeze doesn't throw an error when changing number fields

Tags: angular, ngrx

As far as I understand it, the purpose of [ngrx-store-freeze](https://github.com/brandonroberts/ngrx-store-freeze) is to prevent you from accidentally changing an existing state instead of creating a new object. From their site:

> ngrx-store-freeze is a meta-reducer that prevents state from being mutated
>
> Recursively freezes the current state, the dispatched action payload if provided and the new state.
> When mutation occurs, an exception will be thrown.
> Should be used only in development to ensure that the state remains immutable.

It seems that it doesn't work on primitive types like `number` however.

```
function Reducer(counter : number = 0, action : Action) {
  counter++; // Should trigger an error but it doesn't.
  return counter + 1;
}
```

On the other hand, if I change a field inside an object taken by a Reducer, it works:

```
function NestedReducer(nestedCounter : { counter : number } = { counter : 0 }, action : Action) {
  nestedCounter = { counter : 0 }; // Doesn't trigger an error.
  nestedCounter.counter++; // This does trigger an error.
  return { counter : nestedCounter.counter + 1 };
}
```

Is this the intended behavior? I assume it works similar to C# in that primitive types are copied by value, objects themselves are copied by value but their "value" is really a pointer to the object.

So I assume it's related to this:

```
let a = { counter : 0 };
let b = a;
console.log(`${a.counter}, ${b.counter}`);
b.counter++; // This changes a.counter as well since both a and b reference the same object.
console.log(`${a.counter}, ${b.counter}`);
b = { counter : 0 }; // This does not change a or a.counter, now a and b point to different objects.
console.log(`${a.counter}, ${b.counter}`);
```

And this would print:

```
0, 0
1, 1
1, 0
```

So ngrx-store-freeze will only prevent you from changing properties in the input parameter if it's a composite object, but not from reassigning the variable to reference a different object, or from incrementing it if it's a number type.

Am I correct here?

Comment: where are you using ngrx-store-freeze?

Comment: I encountered it in a project I've been added to. Still trying to figure out why they decided to use it.

Comment: Lol I meant where in your code snippets is being used? As it is, the problem cant be reproduced.

Comment: OK, see https://github.com/sashoalm/ngrx-minimal-app/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts.